# Proving a certain theorem in L1 logic.

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Description of Logic $L_1$:

Primary connectives: $\lnot$ , $\lor$

$A\rightarrow B$ is $\lnot A \lor B$

Axioms:
(A1) $B \lor B \rightarrow B$ 
(A2) $B \rightarrow B \lor C$ 
(A3) $B \lor C \rightarrow C \lor B$ 
(A4) $(C \rightarrow D ) \rightarrow (B \lor C \rightarrow B \lor D)$

The only rule of inference is $MP$

With these , I was able to prove the following theorem about $L_1$

a. $B \rightarrow C \vdash_{L_1} D \lor B \rightarrow D \lor C$ 
b. $\vdash_{L_1} ( B \rightarrow C ) \rightarrow ((D \rightarrow B) \rightarrow (D \rightarrow C))$
c. $D \rightarrow B , B \rightarrow C \vdash_{L_1} D \rightarrow C$
d. $\vdash_{L_1} B \rightarrow B$
e. $\vdash_{L_1} B \lor \lnot B$
f. $\vdash_{L_1} B \rightarrow \lnot \lnot B$ 
g. $\vdash_{L_1} \lnot B \rightarrow (B \rightarrow C)$ 
h. $\vdash_{L_1} B \lor (C \lor D) \rightarrow ((C \lor (B \lor D)) \lor B)$

But I got stumped at the next question:

i. $\vdash_{L_1} ((C \lor (B \lor D)) \lor B) \rightarrow (C \lor (B \lor D))$

I tried every theorem and axiom relentlessly (except the ones with negation) to prove this theorem.My best guess is that it is either so easy that I am missing out. Or , it imvolves theorems with negation.

Can someone give me a clue about this?

Comment: Is it $(C \lor B \lor D \lor B ) \rightarrow C \lor (B \lor D) $ (I know the one B is redundant) or something else?  because if there is a known operator precedence - then we should evaluate $\lor$ before $\rightarrow$... or you meant saying it is actually $(C \lor (B \lor D)) \lor (B \rightarrow C) \lor (B \lor D) $ ?

Comment: I should have put more parenthesis .Thanks for mentioning.

Comment: What about proving that it is a tautology, thus a sentence in $L_1$ (If it is complete, which I assume), or using deduction theorem?

Comment: I was not supposed to use those methods (completeness and deduction) to prove this theorem . Because they are proven much later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have to use (A4) to "import" all the needed transformations:

1. $(D \lor B) \to (B \lor D)$ --- (A3)

Thus, using (A4), we have:

2. $[C \lor (D \lor B)] \to [C \lor (B \lor D)]$.

Consider now: $[(C \lor D) \lor (B \lor B)]$. By (A1) using (A4) we get:

3. $[(C \lor D) \lor (B \lor B)] \to [(C \lor D) \lor B]$

We need also the *Associativity* Lemma:

> $\vdash [(A \lor B) \lor C)] \to [A \lor (B \lor C)]$ to get, by (b):

4. $[(C \lor D) \lor (B \lor B)] \to [C \lor (D \lor B)]$,

Using 2) above and (b) again we get:

> 5. $[(C \lor D) \lor (B \lor B)] \to [C \lor (B \lor D)]$.

Now, the same approach must be used to derive:

6. $[(C ∨ (B ∨ D)) ∨ B] \to [(C \lor D) \lor (B \lor B)].$

---

Proof of *Associativity*:

*Lemma 1*: if $\vdash A \to C$ and $\vdash B \to C$, then $\vdash A \lor B \to C$.

1. $B \to C$
2. $(A \lor B) \to (C \lor A)$ --- from 1) and (A4) with (A3), by *MP*
3. $A \to C$
4. $(C \lor A) \to (C \lor C)$ --- as above

> 5. $(A \lor B) \to C$ --- from 2) and 4) and (A1) using (b).

*Lemma 2*: if $\vdash A \to B$, then $A \to (C \lor B)$ and $A \to (B \lor C)$

1. $A \to B$
2. $A \to (B \lor C)$ --- from 1) and (A2) using (b)
3. $A \lor (C \lor B)$ --- from 2) and (A3).

*Lemma*:

1. $A \to [A \lor (B \lor C)]$ --- (A2)
2. $B \to (B \lor C)$ --- (A2)
3. $B \to [A \lor (B \lor C)]$ --- from 2) by *Lemma 2*
4. $(A \lor B) \to [A \lor (B \lor C)]$ --- from 1) and 3) by *Lemma 1*
5. $C \to  [A \lor (B \lor C)]$ --- from $\vdash C \to C$ [your (d)] and *Lemma 2* twice.

> 6. $\vdash [(A \lor B) \lor C] \to [A \lor (B \lor C)]$ --- from 4) and 5) by *Lemma 1*

Comment: I am having trouble proving the _associativity_ law.Can you show me how ? (It seems like it is beyond me).By the way , your first and second transformation was something that I should have thought of :).

Comment: In the exercises of the textbook I am studying , the theorems (a) to (h) took not more than 4 lines.and after (h) was the ultimate problem that this post was all about.This problem took about ... 42 lines (So the solution was way beyond me) . Can you tell me the strategy you used for  solving this problem ?

Comment: @Prithubiswas - it is the system of [Principia](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/principia-mathematica/). For a modern version, see Anfrews, [An Introduction to Mathematical Logic](https://books.google.it/books?id=UaPuCAAAQBAJ&pg=PA1)