# Showing that $B \rightarrow (C \rightarrow D) , (B \rightarrow C) \vdash_{L_1} (B \rightarrow D)$

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

First of all , I was able to prove that ,

$B \rightarrow (C \rightarrow D) , (B \rightarrow C) \vdash_{L_1} B \rightarrow (B \rightarrow D)$

But I wasn't able to prove from it that ,

$B \rightarrow (C \rightarrow D) , (B \rightarrow C) \vdash_{L_1}  (B \rightarrow D)$

**Description of $L_1 :$**

Primary connectives: $\lnot$ , $\lor$
$A\rightarrow B$ is $\lnot A \lor B$ 
Axioms:
(A1) $B \lor B \rightarrow B$ 
(A2) $B \rightarrow B \lor C$ 
(A3) $B \lor C \rightarrow C \lor B$ 
(A4) $(C \rightarrow D ) \rightarrow (B \lor C \rightarrow B \lor D)$

The only rule of inference is $MP$

One of my attempts:
1.$((B \rightarrow D) \rightarrow D) \rightarrow ((B \rightarrow (B \rightarrow D)) \rightarrow (B \rightarrow D))$

Here,if I was able to show that 
 $B \rightarrow (C \rightarrow D) , (B \rightarrow C) \vdash_{L_1}((B \rightarrow D) \rightarrow D)$ 
  then I could have also shown that ,
 $B \rightarrow (C \rightarrow D) , (B \rightarrow C) \vdash_{L_1}  (B \rightarrow D)$ 
But I am not sure if it is even possible.

Can someone give me a clue about this?

Comment: Deduction Theorem.

Comment: Well , deduction theorem is proved after this theorem for L1 . So I am not supposed to use deduction for this problem. But maybe I can use the technique of proving deduction theorem for L1 to prove this theorem. (maybe)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Hint*

You have proved: $B→(C→D),(B→C)⊢_{L_1} B→(B→D)$.

The premises are the same; rewrite the conclusion as: $\lnot B \lor (\lnot B \lor D)$.

Apply Associativity (your [previous post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3994379/proving-a-certain-theorem-in-l1-logic)) to get: $(\lnot B \lor \lnot B) \lor D$ and the conclusion will follow using (A1), (A4) and Transitivity of $\to$ (result c. of your previous post).

Comment: I should have thought of breaking down implies into its original components.